# How can I pass this variable on click in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass this variable in javascript.

when this  link is clicked I want to pass the post_slug in javascript.

`<li  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<?php echo $post_slug;?>"><a>Edit</a></li>`

In javascript I need the that variable with "imgInp" .

```
 $("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
// (imgInp<?php echo post_slug;?>)  how can I write it in js.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you could use another `data` attribute to hold the slug itself, then read it back and send it as a parameter to the function. Try this:

```html
<li id="slug" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<?php echo $post_slug; ?>" data-slug="imgInp<?php echo $post_slug; ?>">
  <a>Edit</a>
</li>
```

```js
$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  var slug = $('#slug').data('slug');
  readURL(slug);
});
```

Note that I added the `slug` id to the `li` to make selecting it easier. You can use which ever method you prefer to identify the element.

Comment: is the data-slug doing anything ??

Comment: if slug is "123" then i need "imgInp123"

Comment: You can append it: `data-slug="imgInp<?php echo $post_slug; ?>"`